# How do the Turtles get their pizza?

Tags: teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles

In most all incarnations of TMNT, the Ninja Turtles love to eat pizza. But they also try to keep themselves hidden from humans as much as possible.

So this raises a question: **How do the Turtles get their pizza?**

If delivery, from where? And how would they receive said pie?

Comment: Reminds me to the problem the heros of StickManStickMan webcomics face when they need to get pizza but they're on a planet very far from Earth that doesn't sell pizza, in strips 910...914: http://stickman.qntm.org/comics.php?n=910

Comment: They have it sent to the Cryogenic Freezing Center.  They just have it shipped to I.C. Weiner.

Comment: They are ninjas. If they can't swap pizza for cash without the delivery person seeing them then they need to turn in their ninja school diplomas.

Comment: @stonemetal True. But getting a pizza is one of those instances where you will end up coming face to face with another person. For normal ninjas this would be no big deal, but since they're mutant turtles, this complicates things.

Comment: <moderator deletes comments> Please keep comments on-topic. If you want to discuss why pizzas are called "pie," please do so in [chat].

Answer (score 97, accepted):

### Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles (1990)

The Turtles order their pizza for delivery to "*122 **⅛ᵗʰ***". This works to their advantage since the famous [Domino's 30-minute-guarantee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino's_Pizza#30-minute_guarantee) (and relative difficulty in finding the sewer address) means that it ends up being free. They do still tip the guy though.

[image]

### Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles II: The Secret of the Ooze (1991)

They order their pizza for delivery to April's apartment. Since she's out at the time, the plan seems to be to break into her apartment (via the fire escape) and then accept the order at her door, presumably wearing some kind of rudimentary disguise.

The pizzeria owner notes that she's becoming one of their best customers lately (referring to her by name) so it seems that under normal circumstances she's the one to accept the orders. In this case, their plan fails and they simply take the pizza from the pizza-boy after he leaves it lying around.

[image]

### TMNT (2007)

In the 2007 CGI remake, the original script contained these lines;

> MICHAELANGELO : KIDS BYE!!!!!!
>
> ON DOOR - **As the door closes and Mom turns back, a green hand reaches
>   in quickly a grabs a box of pizza.** The door closes.
>
> MICHAELANGELO (O.S.) : Heheh... score.

This scene was cut from the film. There are plenty of pizza boxes but no explanation of how they got there.

### Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles: Out of the Shadows (2016)

The turtles order the food to a street corner and grab it out of the deliverer's hand. He seems oblivious, gawking at his mobile phone.

[image]

---

### [IDW comic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teenage_Mutant_Ninja_Turtles_(IDW_Publishing))

In the comic serials, they largely seem to rely on April or Casey Jones doing the actual collecting.

[image]

### GBX Game

As with many Ninja Turtles games, pizzas act as collectables and simply appear in mid-air

[image]

Comment: That game! Loved it :) ... the graphics still look good!

Comment: This is where all food comes from in video games.  That and garbage cans.  Aaah, fresh Garbabe Burgers...whole roasted Garbage Chickens...exquisite.

Comment: [Rémi knows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUll5SnavOw).

Comment: However if they have to wait so long, the pizza might become cool!

Comment: All the nostalgia.  I need to go back and watch those movies.

Comment: Them tipping the pizza guy opens up another question: Where do they get the money from? They don't have any form of income.

Comment: @Philipp - They spend their time beating up drug dealers. I don't think it's a stretch to assume that once they've knocked them out, that they then rob them.

Comment: @Richard you mean they liberate their wallets I hope?

Comment: @jwenting - I fail to see how anyone could watch an episode of TMNT and not spot that they're a bunch of stoners, like Bill & Ted or Shaggy. They're almost certainly stealing the drugs as well.

Comment: @Philipp - I asked the Director of the Ninja Turtles (1990) film where they got their money from. He said "The props department". Not much help there...

Answer (score 20):

In the 1987 cartoon they use disguises or get April to collect it for them.

Comment: Video link is dead

Answer (score 20):

In the current comic series, Mikey has managed to make friends with a pizza shop worker.  He smuggles pizzas to the turtles out the back door.

[image: The art gets better later.]

Comment: And THERE you have both "pizza" and "pie" in the same sentence.

Answer (score 19):

Donatello sometimes makes them. Here are two examples from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54au0Ve5I50) compilation:

[image: Chocolate chip pizza]

[image]

In the first image we see Michelangelo standing up and exclaiming, in an unconvinced voice, "Chocolate chip pizza??"

In the second we see Donatello pouring something out a saucepan but saying "nothing like a hot old pizza to start the day."

Answer (score -1):

The same way you do, but more ninja-like.  Incidentally, in the original comic books, they didn't like pizza (well, maybe they did, but we don't hear about it).

Comment: They're in New York. Of course they ate pizzas in the Mirage series, although it was less of a touchstone before the cartoon.